# ajax complete callback function is never called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm using Django.

I have the following code

```
var done_cancel_order = function(res, status) {
  alert("xpto");
};

var cancel_order = function() {
  data = {};
  var args = {
    type:"GET",
    url:"/exchange/cancel_order/"+this.id,
    data:data,
    complete:done_cancel_order
  };
  $.ajax(args);
  return false;
};
```

The function var cancel_order is called when I press a button on the page. That url when accessed is does some things on the server side, which I can check indeed are done, and then returns a json specifying whether or not the request was successful. You get:

```
{'status':200, 'message':'order canceled'}
```

The problem is that the callback is never called. I would like to have the callback display to the user the thing that was returned from the server. But even the first alert("xpto") inside the callback is never executed. Why is that?

EDIT:

I have checked that this code:

```
var cancel_order = function() {
  data = {};
  var args = {
    type:"GET",
    url:"/exchange/cancel_order/"+this.id,
    data:data,
    complete: function() { alert("xpto"); }
  };
  $.ajax(args);
  return false;
```

};

displays the same behavior as described above: everything goes great on the server side, but the callback isn't called.

Comment: Sure that `this.id` is defined inside you `cancel_order` function? Anyways you are misusing HTTP protocol, you should not use a `GET` to perform a `DELETE` operation, and you should not include the status inside the body of the response: it's in the header already ^^

Comment: Yes, I am sure that this.is is defined because like I said the function cancel_order is called correctly, this.id has the correct value, the server gets the correct request, completes the request correctly, and sends back the correct response. But the callback function isn't called. And yes, I know about the HTTP protocol, but this is a small part of a django project and I haven't worked out how to use their CSRF tokens in ajax requests, which are only needed for POST/DELETE and so I'm using GET to make sure I get the javascript part of the issue working first of all.

Comment: Try to call `$.ajax(args).done(function(){ console.log('done', arguments) }).fail(function(){ console.log('fail', arguments) });`, then report your console logs.

Comment: You know what...? It says the console.log command comes from dajaxice (that's a django app to do ajax calls). Now obviously in the code I showed you I wasn't using dajaxice at all. So my suspicion now is that dajaxice is intercepting my js and messing it up. I'll try to completely remove dajaxice from my django project and will get back to you in a few minutes.

Comment: Yup! That was it. I uninstalled dajaxice and it's working now. Shit, what a waste of time. If you make an answer saying "make sure dajaxice isn't messing up your js", I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure nothing is messing with your debug tools [e.g. `console.log`], it may end up wrecking your js code, delivering unexpected results.

Comment: Solved. I had dajaxice installed which was messing with my code. I uninstalled it and now it works. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change it to this:

```
function done_cancel_order (res, status) {
  /* remains same */
};
```

I hope, this one would work for you!

Or just simply:

```
complete: alert("xpto");
```

Comment: Hi! If I do that, then cancel_order isn't done successfully. The server never gets the request.

Comment: Setting it complete: alert("xpto"); would set the complete event to the return value of the alert, which would not be a callback function.